# spark-submit dependency resolution for spark-csv

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am doing small scala program which converts csv to parquet.
I am using databricks spark-csv.
Here's is my `build.sbt`

```js
name: = "tst"

version: = "1.0"

scalaVersion: = "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies++ = Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % % "spark-core" % "1.6.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % % "spark-sql" % "1.6.1",
  "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.5.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % % "spark-hive" % "1.6.1",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-csv" % "1.1",
  "com.univocity" % "univocity-parsers" % "1.5.1",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.5" % "provided",
  "org.scalatest" % % "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test",
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.9" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.3.11",
  "org.scalatest" % % "scalatest" % "2.2.1",
  "com.holdenkarau" % % "spark-testing-base" % "1.6.1_0.3.3",
  "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.5.0",
  "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.8.1"

)
```

After `sbt package`, when I run command

`spark-submit --master local[*]  target/scala-2.10/tst_2.10-1.0.jar`

I get following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
```

I can see the `com.databricks_spark-csv_2.10-1.5.0.jar` file in `~/.ivy2/jars/` downloaded by `sbt package` command

The source code of the `dataconversion.scala`

```js
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object dataconversion {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf =
      new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("ClusterScore")
      .set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "1")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlc = new SQLContext(sc)
    val df = sqlc.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
      .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
      .load("/tmp/cars.csv")
    println(df.printSchema)
  }

}
```

I can do `spark-submit` without error if I specify `--jars` option with explicit `jar` path. But that's not ideal. Please suggest.

Comment: Just a nitpick, replace `"com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.5.0"` with `"com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0"`. Mind `%%` and no Scala version in the dependency to make `build.sbt` *less* error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin to build a "fat jar" containing *all* your dependencies with `sbt assembly`, and then call `spark-submit` on that.

In general, when you get `ClassNotFoundException`, try exploding the jar you created to see what's in it with `jar tvf target/scala-2.10/tst_2.10-1.0.jar`. Checking what's in the Ivy cache is meaningless; that just tells you that SBT found it. As mathematicians say, that's necessary but not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned library is required so you have options:

1. Place `com.databricks_spark-csv_2.10-1.5.0.jar` in local or hdfs
   reachable path and provide as dependency with `--jars` parameter
2. Using `--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0` which will
   provide required lib to your process
3. To build fat jar with your dependencies and forget about `--jars`